# Open a new window to display a html file using a menu click - Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and JavaScript. I'm building an Electron app. I know how to open a URL in a browser via clicking an item in native menu(by studying the documentation), but I need to open a html file in another Electron window using an Electron's native menu click. If I have my menu structure like below, how can I achieve this? Please help.

```
const {Menu} = require('electron');

const nativeMenus = [
    {
        label: 'About',
        submenu: [
            {
                label: 'About',
                click () {--- code to open about.html file in another electron window}
            }
        ]

    }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(nativeMenus);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Comment: window.open() as here https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If it is all in the main.js just create a function to create a new window and then call that on menu item click.

```
const { Menu } = require('electron')
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer

const nativeMenus = [
  {
    label: 'About',
    submenu: [
      {
        label: 'About',
        click() {
          openAboutWindow()
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(nativeMenus)
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)

var newWindow = null

function openAboutWindow() {
  if (newWindow) {
    newWindow.focus()
    return
  }

  newWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 185,
    resizable: false,
    width: 270,
    title: '',
    minimizable: false,
    fullscreenable: false
  })

  newWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/views/about.html')

  newWindow.on('closed', function() {
    newWindow = null
  })
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Many thanks. But my menu script is also in the main.js file. So how can resolve the const variable `ipc`?

Comment: In that case it even easier, I will update the cod to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You stored your `BrowserWindow` instance in a variable, for the sake of this answer I am gonna suppose it's `win`. user7252292 did provide you with a good answer. But if you need another window then you will have to create another function for the same purpose. I will make a function for creating `modals`. They are basically windows that need a parent window and you cannot respond to the parent window until the modal is closed.

```
const createModal = (htmlFile, parentWindow, width, height) => {
  let modal = new BrowserWindow({
    width: width,
    height: height,
    modal: true,
    parent: parentWindow,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  modal.loadFile(htmlFile)

  return modal;

}

const {Menu} = require('electron');

const nativeMenus = [
  {
      label: 'About',
      submenu: [
          {
            label: 'About',
             click () {

              createModal("myfile.html",win,600,800); // Win is the browerwindow instance

            }
        }
    ]
  }
]

const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(nativeMenus);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Plus, you can store the createModal in a variable and modify the modal because it returns the modal itself.